# Click on table row to fire both javascript and .net server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a pop-up div contains a table.

Due to some issues, I need to make table rows clickable and can be catched by both js and .net server side .

Can or how can I use Request.form to solve this issue? since I've created functions for js part .

Or any other suggestions?

The reason why I want to fire sever side event, because I use JS to add option (item) to an asp:ddl in an updatepanel, it will cause error or lose the new option by doing a postback fired by other buttons.

Or any better solutions to this?

Regards

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ajax and http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/Using-jQuery-with-ASP-NET.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this topic if you want to [simulate a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159806/how-do-i-synthesize-a-browser-click-event-on-a-div-element/5159857) event.

Comment: I finally found a solution to allow JS call the server side code, probably is not same as ur links. Anyway thx for you answer.