# How do I synthesize a browser click event on a DIV element?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, dom-events

With buttons, I can call the `click()` method on them to have a click generated. DIVs however don't have this method on all browsers. Yet I can attach click event listeners to them (by either setting `.onclick="..."` or adding an event listener).

Is there any way for me to "synthesize" a click on such an element programmatically, but **without using jQuery**? Ideally this will not be dependent on a specific way of the listeners being registered (so simply calling `eval(div.onclick)` will not work for me), and work in all modern browsers.

(For the curious, I need this for automated testing, not tricking users.)

Comment: If click doesn't work, then using onmousedown/onmouseup can be used as a workaround. Without either of those, the standard drag 'n drop libraries wouldn't work.

Comment: So - let me get this straight - you want cross browser javascript - and do not want to use jQuery? You are either setting yourself up for failure or a lot of hard work.

Comment: why is eval(div.onclick) not working for you?

Comment: @wiifm No he is not, it is not difficult either. People rely way too heavily on jQuery. If you did a bit of research you would find a cross browser implementation that takes no more than nine short lines.

Comment: @wiifm There could be a million of legitimate reasons NOT to use it. My question, after all, was not "Should I use jQuery if I want to...".

Comment: @Wolfy87 how many 'short lines' do you need before you have written your own (independent) js library? Something to think about. @levik I am glad this solution works for you

Comment: @wiifm: Many. Just under 3000 in my case. But a stand alone function is small. If you only have a small amount of JavaScript functionality on a page then why not write your own function(s).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently wrote a function to do just this into my library, it can be found in the GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/Wolfy87/Spark/blob/master/src/trigger.js).

It is completely cross browser and triggers the specified event on the elements returned by the selector engine. I am sure you will be able to extract the code you need from it.

If not, here is what you need. Replace element with, well, the element. And type with the type of event, in this case, `click`.

```
// Check for createEventObject
if(document.createEventObject){
    // Trigger for Internet Explorer
    trigger = document.createEventObject();
    element.fireEvent('on' + type, trigger);
}
else {
    // Trigger for the good browsers
    trigger = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    trigger.initEvent(type, true, true);
    element.dispatchEvent(trigger);
}
```

Here is an example implementation.

```
function simulateEvent(element, type) {
    // Check for createEventObject
    if(document.createEventObject){
        // Trigger for Internet Explorer
        trigger = document.createEventObject();
        element.fireEvent('on' + type, trigger);
    }
    else {
        // Trigger for the good browsers
        trigger = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        trigger.initEvent(type, true, true);
        element.dispatchEvent(trigger);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your browser is DOM compatible you can use the `dispatchEvent(evt)` method of the DIV element.

For more see the [dom w3c spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/ecma-script-binding.html).

Comment: Does "DOM compatible" include any versions of IE?

Comment: Nope. Well I know that anything lower than IE9 does not support it. I am not sure about IE9 but it probably does (fingers crossed Microsoft got it right this time!).